# How do i add the svg files next to my table rows sow they would look neat like in the photo attched

Tags: svg, html-table

So i am building my website for transportation services.

in the form where i ask the user for "pickup" and "destination" i want to achieve a neat Googlish look.
You can see googles "from" and "to" form here:

[This is the Google wanted style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmyDN.png)
[This is What i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffC5d.png)

https://www.google.com/search?q=get+a+ride&oq=get+a+ride&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j0j69i60j0.1495j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
 (it shows only in mobile view)

now the way i have tried was inserting the svg paths inside the table like this: (Don't mind the Rtl direction i need it that way)

```html
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="place_from" id="from-input" class="txt" placeholder="From" /></td> .   
    <td><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="10px" height="10px" viewBox="0 65.326 612 502.174" enable-background="new 0 65.326 612 502.174"
      xml:space="preserve" class="dot-circle">

    <path class="st0" d="M256,8C119,8,8,119,8,256s111,248,248,248s248-111,248-248S393,8,256,8z M366.9,256
     c0,61.1-49.7,110.9-110.9,110.9S145.1,317.1,145.1,256S194.9,145.1,256,145.1S366.9,194.9,366.9,256z"/>
    </svg></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#878787;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M256,504 M335.8,256c0,44-35.8,79.8-79.8,79.8S176.2,300,176.2,256s35.8-79.8,79.8-79.8S335.8,212,335.8,256z"/>
    </svg></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="place_to" id="to-input" class="txt" placeholder="To" /></td>
    <td><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#878787;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M256,504 M335.8,256c0,44-35.8,79.8-79.8,79.8S176.2,300,176.2,256s35.8-79.8,79.8-79.8S335.8,212,335.8,256z"/>
    </svg></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 384 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 384 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#878787;}
    </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M172.3,501.7C27,291,0,269.4,0,192C0,86,86,0,192,0s192,86,192,192c0,77.4-27,99-172.3,309.7
     C202.2,515.4,181.8,515.4,172.3,501.7L172.3,501.7z M192,272c44.2,0,80-35.8,80-80s-35.8-80-80-80s-80,35.8-80,80S147.8,272,192,272z"/>
    </svg></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you see, it looks bad and my question is **what is the best method to get the closest to what google has?**

Here is the link for my website so far: http://moveus.co.il/wp/moveus/

------Update!

I have tried creating a table with `<div>`s and got a similar result but higher margins which i cant seam to affect with css:
[This is what i achieved with div table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN9yY.png)

```css
     .tablewrapper {
      position: relative;
    }
    .table {
      display: table;
      
    }
    .row {
      display: table-row;
    
    
    }
    .cell {
      border: 1px solid ;
      display: table-cell;
      
      
    }
    .cell.empty
    {
      border: none;
      width: 100px;
      
    }
    .cell.rowspanned {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100px;
      
    }
    
    .st0 {
        fill:#878787;
        transform: scale(0.1);
       
        
    }
    
    .st1 {
        fill:#878787;
        transform: scale(0.2);
    
       
    }
    
    .st4 {
        fill:#878787;
        transform: scale(0.2);
    
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tablewrapper">
    <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><input type="text" name="place_from" id="from-input" class="txt" /></div>
    <div class="rowspanned cell" >
      </svg>
    
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="default">
    <path class="st0" d="M256,8C119,8,8,119,8,256s111,248,248,248s248-111,248-248S393,8,256,8z M366.9,256
     c0,61.1-49.7,110.9-110.9,110.9S145.1,317.1,145.1,256S194.9,145.1,256,145.1S366.9,194.9,366.9,256z"/>
    </svg>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st1" d="M256,504 M335.8,256c0,44-35.8,79.8-79.8,79.8S176.2,300,176.2,256s35.8-79.8,79.8-79.8S335.8,212,335.8,256z"
     />
    </svg>
    
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st1" d="M256,504 M335.8,256c0,44-35.8,79.8-79.8,79.8S176.2,300,176.2,256s35.8-79.8,79.8-79.8S335.8,212,335.8,256z"
     />
    </svg>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st1" d="M256,504 M335.8,256c0,44-35.8,79.8-79.8,79.8S176.2,300,176.2,256s35.8-79.8,79.8-79.8S335.8,212,335.8,256z"
     />
    </svg>
    
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 384 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 384 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st4" d="M172.3,501.7C27,291,0,269.4,0,192C0,86,86,0,192,0s192,86,192,192c0,77.4-27,99-172.3,309.7
     C202.2,515.4,181.8,515.4,172.3,501.7L172.3,501.7z M192,272c44.2,0,80-35.8,80-80s-35.8-80-80-80s-80,35.8-80,80S147.8,272,192,272
     z"/>
    </svg>
    </svg>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"><input type="text" name="place_to" id="to-input" class="txt" /></div>
    <div class="empty cell">&nbsp;</div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post a screen shot.  Not everyone wants to find your post in their mobile browser.  Plus that feature may not be available to everyone.  Or it might change in the future and then your question becomes less useful.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau done. sorry some how i missed it from the original post.

Comment: It looks like what you have now is pretty close to the screenshot. At least when I look at it in Chrome.  What else where you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i have included the desired outcome now, please take another look.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it a lot easier if you merge your five SVGs into one SVG.

Then you can use flex-box to stack your inputs into a column. Then use flex-box again to put that stack and your SVG into a row.

```
[ I N P U T ]  SVG
 s p a c e r   SVG
[ I N P U T ]  SVG
```

Demo:

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.form input {
  height: 27px;
}

.form .spacer {
  height: 27px;
}

.form .svg {
  padding-left: 1em;
}

svg {
  width: 27px;
  height: 100%;
}


.st0 {
  fill:#878787;
}
    
.st1 {
  fill:#878787;
}
    
.st4 {
  fill:#878787;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="field-column">
    <div><input type="text" name="place_from" id="from-input" class="txt" /></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="place_to" id="to-input" class="txt" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="svg">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 1536">
      <path class="st0" d="M256,8C119,8,8,119,8,256s111,248,248,248s248-111,248-248S393,8,256,8z M366.9,256c0,61.1-49.7,110.9-110.9,110.9S145.1,317.1,145.1,256S194.9,145.1,256,145.1S366.9,194.9,366.9,256z"
            transform="translate(58,0) scale(0.77, 0.77)"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="256" cy="540" r="60"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="256" cy="750" r="60"/>
      <circle class="st1" cx="256" cy="960" r="60"/>
      <path class="st4" d="M172.3,501.7C27,291,0,269.4,0,192C0,86,86,0,192,0s192,86,192,192c0,77.4-27,99-172.3,309.7    C202.2,515.4,181.8,515.4,172.3,501.7L172.3,501.7z M192,272c44.2,0,80-35.8,80-80s-35.8-80-80-80s-80,35.8-80,80S147.8,272,192,272z"
            transform="translate(58,1120)"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it was allot easier merging all the elements to one svg.

Comment: Hi Paul, quick question. let's consider this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1jxp4n3y/1/. Why on the second example the gradient direction is not perpendicular to the green line? shouldn't both gradient provide the same angle (45deg). I am not able to get the logic behind drawing the gradient. I found this in the specification *the gradient normal which is initially perpendicular to the gradient vector within object bounding box space may render non-perpendicular relative to the gradient vector in user space. ...* but I didn't get it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The green line actually is perpendicular *in untransformed space*. It just appears wrong because the gradient is using `objectBoundingBox` coords and you have stretched the width (and hence the gradient) by 3x.  If you [scale it in X by 1/3 again](https://jsfiddle.net/wjhv40t1/1/) you will see what's happening.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau *you have stretched the width* but I have also changed the viewbox to match the width of the rect so why it's considered as stretched? :/ .. should I understand that gradient are only defined considering a square then I stretch the square to match the rect area?

Comment: even if I remove the CSS width/height it's the same (https://jsfiddle.net/dtwf451a/1/). The story of coordinates is confusing me ... do you have any official reference showing precise details about how its done behind the scene? The specification isn't very clear and always use square shapes to illustrate.

Comment: This should be a new question. But in brief, you are stretching `objectBoundingBox` space (ie. 1.0 x 1.0) onto a rectangle that is 300 x 100.